# Deploy the GWT Application to the Other host

Tags: gwt, deployment

Is it Compulsory to Deploy the GWT Applications to the appspot.com ?
Can I use other hosting service ? My country is in App Engine site's Forbidden Countries, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deploying GWT involves:

**(1) Creating Javascript from Java for the client code.** If this is all you are doing, you can deploy these files to any web host, it doesn't even need to provide PHP or anything dynamic at all. (For example I created a Sudoku solver which does no calls to the server, and I just put the generated Javascript on my cheap shared host where my blog lives.)

**(2) Deploying the Java on the server-side,** which the Javascript calls. In which case you can use any host which is capable of running Java. appspot is one such example, but you can e.g. rent your own root servers and install Java and Tomcat and install your server-side GWT code there, for example [here](http://www.nessus.at/produkte/rootserver/) or [here](http://www.1und1.info/xml/order/ServerPremium) or anywhere else.

One thing to note is, that due to the nature of AJAX calls ([same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)) if you are installing both (1) and (2) then they need to be reachable under the same URL, which probably means that they both need to be installed on the same server.

Comment: This is valid information, but Iein's answer addresses the asker's question more correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can "deploy" your GWT app anywhere. App engine is great, but if you want to use your own server see instructions here:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideDeploying.html